# GAE/J Channel API exception even though messages go through?

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, channel-api

I open a channel during the app initialization through a series of ajax calls:

```
getToken = function () {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "/game?action=getChannelToken", true);
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status==200) {
            connect(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
};
```

Servlet:

```
ChannelService channelService = ChannelServiceFactory.getChannelService();
channelToken = channelService.createChannel(uid);
```

The token is then returned to the javascript for:

```
connect = function (token) {
//  alert ("connect");
    var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
    var socket = channel.open();
    socket.onopen = onOpened;
    socket.onmessage = onMessage;
    socket.onerror = onError;
    socket.onclose = onClose;
};
```

I'm getting this error:

> WARNING: /_ah/channel/dev
>   com.google.appengine.api.channel.dev.LocalChannelFailureException:
>   Channel for application key null not
>   found.

The channel creation part is very simple, so I do not understand where is the problem.
`System.out.println (channelToken);` returns something like

> channel--rrmk8i-100002139544068

(100002139544068 is the uid I used to create the channel), so it seems to return a real token. Moreover, `channelService.sendMessage(msg);` (using the same uid as before), sends the message without any problem.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
I'm using eclipse 3.5.2, GAE/J 1.4.2 and ubuntu 10.10

Googling for that exception I found only one discussion here: 
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/19f250b1ff0e4342

but changing `var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);` to `var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(uid);` did not solve anything (and, from what I understand, it shouldn't)

Comment: Sorry, I should add that I'm running it on localhost and that socket.onError is not called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two reasons this could be happening:

1. You're restarting the dev_appserver.py while your client is still running. Because the client will be polling with an "old" token that the dev_appserver doesn't know about, it will throw this error. If this is the case, just refresh your client page after restarting the dev_appserver (or otherwise force it to request a new token).
2. connect() is being called with an invalid token. It sounds like you've ruled that out but if the above isn't true it might be worth double-checking.

You can see what token the client is polling with you can open up Firebug or the Chrome dev console and look for requests to a path like this:

`http://localhost:8080/_ah/channel/dev?command=poll&channel=channel-1503856530-alpha-token&client=1`

The `channel-1503856530-alpha-token` part of that URL is the token passed to "`new goog.appengine.Channel()`".

Comment: Indeed I was restarting the server as part of the java servlet debugging. I will test it tonight but I'm pretty sure that's the case. I always refreshed the client page before continuing and that's probably why everything else worked just fine.

Comment: I also wanted to thank you for your quick reply. It is a pleasure to use a platform knowing that the devs are there to help.

Comment: Answering questions is one of my favorite parts of my job! Glad to help.